# wamp server 1045 error?

Tags: php, joomla, wamp

I had installed wamp server and joomla on my local machine. It was giving phpmyadmin no access error 1045. I followed some instructions on the net and everything was fixed. I had to delete that installation because on error in joomla installation. Now when I am trying to install wamp again I am getting the same phpmyadmin error. Tried everything but could not get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be using the wrong username, password, or host to log in. Or have a mismatch between what you think it's set as, and what it really is set as in the database.

Or phpmyadmin's config.inc.php file has the wrong account info, or is using the wrong method to log in.

Try another WAMP package and be careful when changing database account info (know what the account's Host field is for, it should always be localhost or 127.0.0.1).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs

Comment: I have done a fresh install. In installation wamp server did not ask any password. how can i find out the default password for user root.

Comment: @HasanZubairi, which WAMP did you install?

Comment: I tried wamp server 2.2 and xampp server both with same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried entering your root password into the config.inc.php file (found in Wamp's apps > phpmyadmin folder)? (Also, have you seen [this thread at Wamp's official site](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,24792,24807)?)